# URLSession.shared.dataTask block not running

Tags: swift, completionhandler

I'm trying to make a request to an API. Without the completion handler, the request proceeds without issue. However, now that I've added in a completion handler, the URLSession.shared.dataTask block doesn't appear to run at all; the second print statement never prints. How should I adjust my code to fix this issue?

```
func makeRequestToApi(word: String, completionHandler: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
        var array = [String]()
        let appId = ""
        let appKey = ""
        let language = "en-us"
        let unwrappedURL = URL(string: "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v2/entries/\(language)/\(word)")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: unwrappedURL)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue(appId, forHTTPHeaderField: "app_id")
        request.addValue(appKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "app_key")
        print("THIS STATEMENT PRINTS...")
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            print("AND THIS STATEMENT")
            if let data = data,
                let _ = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) {
                do {
                    let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
                    let results = root.results
                    for result in results {
                        for lexical in result.lexicalEntries {
                            for entry in lexical.entries {
                                for sense in entry.senses {
                                    for example in sense.examples {
                                        array.append(example.text)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                completionHandler(array)
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

This is the function that I used on another view controller that returned data for the same words:

```
func makeRequestToApi() {
        let appId = ""
        let appKey = ""
        let language = "en-us"
        let strictMatch = "false"
        var word = search
        word = word.lowercased()
        let oxDicURL = URL(string: "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v2/entries/\(language)/\(word)?strictMatch=\(strictMatch)")
        if let unwrappedURL = oxDicURL {
            var request = URLRequest(url: unwrappedURL)
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            request.addValue(appId, forHTTPHeaderField: "app_id")
            request.addValue(appKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "app_key")
            let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                if let data = data,
                    let _ = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) {
                    do {
                        let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
                        let results = root.results
                        for result in results {
                            for lexical in result.lexicalEntries {
                                for entry in lexical.entries {
                                    for sense in entry.senses {
                                        for example in sense.examples {
                                            print(example.text)
                                            self.array.append(example.text)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        self.search = word
                        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToDetail", sender: nil)
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
            dataTask.resume()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question but delete the pointless `JSONSerialization` expression.

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling `makeRequestToApi` anywhere in your code?

Comment: @LeoDabus He might do, since he prints `THIS STATEMENT PRINTS.. ` and `AND THIS STATEMENT`. Guess he clarified for us.

Comment: @Putte I've just realised that but still makes no sense

Comment: either `data` is `nil`, or the result of `try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)` is `nil` (also, why do you need mutable containers?)

Comment: @LeoDabus this is how I call the function. Is it correct? `makeRequestToApi(word: thisWord) { (examplesList) in
                    print("examples for this word: \(examplesList)")
                    let examplesIndex: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(examplesList.count)))
                    let selection = examplesList[examplesIndex] as String
                    self.dataSource.append(selection)
                }`

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica it should print it anyway even if data is nil

Comment: What happens if you print your url? Try to print that URL, copy it and paste it in a webpage to see the result.

Comment: @heliona203 not related to your question but make sure to percent encode your query word.